# How to prevent min-width overriding max-width?

Tags: html, css

I've created a div that i want to be 50% (for arguments sake) but at least a certain width and at most 100% width, (so that it never extends the window)

```
.about {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Basically, i want the min-width to work, but i want the max-width to be considered MORE important so that it is never wider than the window, i assumed that i could do this by the order, or at least by using !important, but this doesn't seem to be the case

https://jsfiddle.net/ex716kam/2/

Comment: The value of the `min-width` property overrides both `max-width` and `width`. Learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp).

Comment: Ok, i am confused. You want div to be 50% correct. But then "at least certain width" meaning not below certain width. Right. Then that's what's happening, so where is the problem.

Comment: So, you want your div to be at least 500px wide, but never exceed the window width? So what happens if the window is less than 500px? How can it satisfy the "at least 500px wide" condition? Your intent is logically flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've given it a few tries but I can't seem to make it work with CSS alone.
I would recommend using simple javascript or media queries to make it work.

[Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ex716kam/4/)

```
@media screen and (min-width:1000px){
    .about{
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

Note what @lmgonzalves wrote about min-width being the "strongest"..

Comment: Yeah, i figured media queries would work for this case, but because it's quite nice numbers it's easy to work out, and also because i'm using %, but if the units were 'em' or something it might be a little more difficult.

Comment: It's a little strange that you can't prioritize min-width over max-width even using inline styles or important tags, i'd prefer to not have to use media queries too much if possible but it seems the best option here

Answer (score 2):

Just switch the values of min-width and width:

```
.about {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 500px;
    min-width: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8fkbp9d0/

Comment: maybe a bit late but i hope i could help you :)

Comment: This is so simple that I feel dumb for not having that idea myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know what behaviour you expect between 1000px down to 500px, but a media query is the simplest way to achieve what you're looking for:

```css
.about {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width: 50%;
    min-width:500px;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 500px ){
  .about {
    width: 100%;
    min-width:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `max-width: 100%;` use `max-width:100vw;`. It will not go out of your window.

Comment: this seemed interesting, but i just tried it and it didn't solve the problem, could you include a working jsfiddle?

Comment: I have changed your CSS here. Just using these units smarty can solve you problem. https://jsfiddle.net/shishirT20/ex716kam/7/

Answer (score 0):

try this code, this code will work when screen width will be between 500px to 100% screen resolution.

```
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 800px)
{
.about {
        position:absolute;
        right:0;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`min()` function does the trick. Insert your `max-width` as an argument. This way `min-width` can never be wider than your `max-width`

```
min-width: min(500px, 100%);
max-width: 100%;
```

Currently supported in all major browsers except IE:
[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-math-functions)